# Passing arguments to another .c file

Tags: c, atmel

I've looked around for a good while if someone else has posted the same question and I haven't seen found an answer that applies to me.

Heres my problem:
When I pass 3 arguments (located in main) to another .c file, the information erases. If I keep the function inside main (not passing the arguments to another .c file) the program works just fine.

What am I missing here?

Also, I'm using a microcontroller, but I'm sure the problem is in my code.

main:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "glcd.h"
#include "fonts/Liberation_Sans15x21_Numbers.h"


//functions used:
void glcd_print_clock(void);
void time_clock(void);
void display_clock_text(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t z);


int main(void)
{
    glcd_init();

    while(1)
    {
        time_clock();
    }

}

//
void time_clock(void)
{
    uint8_t sec, min, hr;
    //char str_time[8] = "";

    for(hr=1; hr<13; hr++)
    {
        for(min=0; min<60; min++)
        {
            for(sec=0; sec<60; sec++)
            {

                display_clock_text(hr,min,sec);

                /*
                //clears buffer
                glcd_clear_buffer();
                glcd_set_font(Liberation_Sans15x21_Numbers,15,21,46,57);
                //sends hr, min, and sec to string
                sprintf(str_time,"%02d:%02d:%02d",hr,min,sec);
                //x-y coordinate of text
                glcd_draw_string_xy(12,5,str_time);
                //displays text
                glcd_write();
                _delay_ms(1000);
                */

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other .c file (display_text):

```
#include "glcd.h"
#include "fonts/Liberation_Sans15x21_Numbers.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define Y_AXIS  5
#define X_AXIS  12

void display_clock_text(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t z);


/*  Gets the hour, minutes and seconds from main.
    Then displays the information on the LCD
*/
void display_clock_text(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t z)
{
    char str_time[8] = "";

    //clears buffer
    glcd_clear_buffer();

    //selects font to be used
    glcd_set_font(Liberation_Sans15x21_Numbers,15,21,46,57);

    //sends hr, min, and sec to string
    sprintf(str_time,"%02d:%02d:%02d", x, y, z);

    //x-y coordinate of text
    glcd_draw_string_xy(X_AXIS,Y_AXIS,str_time);

    //displays text
    glcd_write();

    _delay_ms(1000);
}
```

Comment: maybe 8 is one too less?

Comment: ... but the UB happens to work in the other function, for unknown reasons.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that the comment block that's inside of main is what I meant by not passing the argument to the other .c file.

Comment: @WeatherVane undefined behavior is undefined behavior. It just happened to work well. Yoy must not rely on that.

Comment: @MikeCAT sorry for my unclear comment, I meant exactly that. It happened to work in the other function. Which is what I wrote. The three dots at the front of my comment were a follow on from the previous comment, which pointed out why it didn't work in the function it didn't work in. I then said it only **happened** to work in the function it *did* work in, for unknown reasons. Geddit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `char str_time[8] = "";` is incorrect.  It should be `char str_time[9] = "";`.  This is because `sprintf(str_time,"%02d:%02d:%02d", x, y, z);` requires 9 bytes because of the terminating 0.

Also, a good idea, in general, would be:

```
snprintf(str_time, sizeof(str_time), "%02d:%02d:%02d", x, y, z);
```

This may or may not be causing the undesirable behavior that you are experiencing but it for sure needs to be fixed.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much. Can you please explain why it requires 9 bytes due to the terminating 0? I'm not sure if I completely understood that. When I count str_time, I count a total of 8 characters.

Comment: Let's say we are working with ASCII characters.  Then, in C, a string is a sequence of characters terminated by a NUL character (hex 00).  This is also called ASCIIZ.  Because sprintf generates one of these "C strings", then a format specifier of "%02d:%02d:%02d" needs a buffer of nine bytes.  For example, if we were storing "12:30:29", then this would be "31 32 3A 33 30 3A 32 29 00" in hex.  Notice that this is nine bytes and that the last byte is 00.  If we ran strlen() on this string, it would report a length of 8 even though 9 bytes are required to store the string.